# Separate initialization for each worker in Flask+Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask

> Design:-

My flask application views contact an API endpoint during the lifetime of requests. Each of these API requests require a token. Due to the server side limitation, I can't have two threads using the same token for initiating requests.

> Requirement:-

- To contact this API, I need to fetch an API token. I would like to do this once per worker and then share that value among views. (just a read-only variable).
- I want each "worker" that serves requests to have a separate "token". How can that be achieved in Flask?
- I don't want to issue a fresh token each time a request is served as that'll be horribly slow.

Comment: @dirn I've not tried because the solution is unknown to me. How do we store a variable that's local to a worker?

Comment: You really need to try yourself before posting a question. You've spent 6 hours waiting for an answer; you may have saved yourself a lot of time if you had just tried to see if this is how gunicorn workers work.

Comment: You might want to take at look at redis or another database to handle server side cache.

Comment: @CESCO What I want is, a separate value for each worker. I'm not sure how can we accomplish that in Redis.

Comment: I think that if all instances look at the same place you wont need to have  individual token for each session, like http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/

Comment: @CESCO My requirement is to have separate tokens for each worker, that's because of the API server I'm using. It doesn't allow two concurrent requests with the same token.